# Trying to add more variables to line graph, get "arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 28, 21"

Tags: r, dataframe

Im doing a line graph, and it worked before, but when i tried adding more variables i kept getting an error

I've tried setting the number at the end of `"Day=rep(c("Day 0", "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3"),4),"` 
to "5", and any other numbers i change it to just gives me a different number at the error message

This is the code that had worked before:

```
df2 <- data.frame(solvent=rep(c("Control",
                                  "Isopropanol",
                                  "DMSO",
                                  "Ethanol"), each=4),
                  Day=rep(c("Day 0", "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3"),4),
                  concentration=c(0.500, 80.5325,   73.46155,   44.55162,
                        0.500, 31.64383, 24.52091,  18.50862,
                        0.500, 55.40918,    45.16291,   36.05471,
                        0.500, 57.39699,    53.51239,   43.26611))


d2 <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=Day, y=concentration, group = solvent)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
d2
```

this is the code im trying to get to work:

```
df2 <- data.frame(solvent=rep(c("Control",
                                "Benzothiophene",
                                  "Isopropanol",
                                  "DMSO",
                                  "Ethanol"), each=4),
                  Day=rep(c("Day 0", "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3"),4),
                  concentration=c(0.500, 80.5325,   73.46155,   44.55162,
                        0.500, 0.146, 0.121, 0,109,
                        0.500, 31.64383, 24.52091,  18.50862,
                        0.500, 55.40918,    45.16291,   36.05471,
                        0.500, 57.39699,    53.51239,   43.26611))


d2 <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=Day, y=concentration, group = solvent)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
d2
```

This is the error message i get:

```
Error in data.frame(solvent = rep(c("Control", "Benzothiophene", "Isopropanol",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 28, 21
```

And the error message when i change the number after "Day" to 5 is:

```
Error in data.frame(solvent = rep(c("Control", "Benzothiophene", "Isopropanol",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 21
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear. When you are trying to create `df2` , your columns `solvent`, `Day` and `concentration` are not of same length. They all should be of same length to be in data frame.

Comment: There's 21 value of concentration in your new frame.